# how to make neural network implementation in c++ efficient?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, neural-network

I have a C++ code, which I evaluate for various inputs repetitively, the network properties are read from another file. The cost of an evaluation is high bc of repetitive declaration and deletion of variables (my guess), any idea on how to reduce it:

```
void NN_eval(Network *net, double rsq, double &Z)
{
    double r;
    int layer;
    r = sqrt(rsq);
    double *L_k, *L_kp;
    L_k = new double [1];
    L_kp = new double [net->archtwobody[1]];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < net->archtwobody[1]; i++)
        L_kp[i] = 0.0;
    L_k[0] = -(r-cutmax)/cutmax;
    int *A_size = new int [2];
    for (layer = 0 ; layer < net->num_layertwobody+1; layer ++ ){
        A_size[0] = net->archtwobody[layer]; A_size[1] = net->archtwobody[layer+1];

        net->multiply(net->Wtwobody[layer], A_size, L_k, L_kp);
        net->add_bias(net->btwobody[layer], A_size[1], L_kp);
        net->apply_nonlinearity(net->functwobody[layer], L_kp, A_size[1]);

        delete [] L_k;
        L_k = new double [net->archtwobody[layer+1]];
        for (int i = 0; i <net->archtwobody[layer+1]; i++) {
            L_k[i] = L_kp[i];
        }
        delete [] L_kp;

        if (layer != net->num_layertwobody){
            L_kp = new double [net->archtwobody[layer+2]];
            for (int i = 0 ; i < net->archtwobody[layer+2]; i++)
                L_kp[i] = 0.0;
        } else{
          L_kp = new double [net->archtwobody[layer+1]];
          for (int i = 0 ; i < net->archtwobody[layer+1]; i++)
              L_kp[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    Z = L_k[0]*net->fmax2;
    delete [] L_k;
    delete [] L_kp;
    delete [] A_size;
}
```

Comment: Don't guess, profile it.

Comment: I am almost sure, I have another code with only one difference, being hard-coded without the need to declare variables multiple times and delete them.

Comment: You can maybe declare `L_k` and `L_kp` as [std::vector<double>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to manage reallocations for you. Then you can get the pointer to underlying array with [data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) method and set the data with the code like `v.assign(num_elems, 0.0);` or from C arrays if needed `double* cdata; ...; v.assign(cdata, cdata + size)`.

Comment: That's what I thought but unfortunately, this code is part of a bigger project and they are not okay using vector library.